# C++ member initialization list question

Tags: c++

```
class TreeNode {
   // An object of type TreeNode represents one node
   // in a binary tree of strings.
   public:
      // Constructor.  Make a node containing str.
      TreeNode(string str) : item(str), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}

      string item;      // The data in this node.
      TreeNode *left;    // Pointer to left subtree.
      TreeNode *right;   // Pointer to right subtree.
};
```

In 6th line, can I delete this part ?

```
   : item(str), left(NULL), right(NULL)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't -- that part initializes the fields of the `TreeNode` class when you construct it.  If you remove the part you mention, the fields will be given either default-constructed or undefined values.

Comment: but I tried to remove it and compile it under gcc. everything was right.

Comment: Or, if I delete the whole line. compiler will provide me a default constructor, right? Is this acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it will look like it works, but the nodes will all have empty `item` fields.  A default constructor would have a similar problem.  Neither would end up with the pointers being set to NULL or meaningful values, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Andy: Undefined behavior includes "everything *seems* to work fine".